# My bubble sort method does not sort. It writes the same name again and again. It should sort Person(String name, int year) by year

Tags: java, object, bubble-sort

I am new to programming and in a course to learn.

In this assignment have to make a class, Person(String name, int year).
Then make a bubble sort, that sorts the Person objects by year.
And I need to test it by writing the names in the console sorted by year.

I am soooo stuck and the same name is written in the console 5 times.

```
public class Person {
    private static String name;
    private static int year;

    public Person(String name, int year) {
        super();
        Person.name = name;
        Person.year = year;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void setName(String name) {
        Person.name = name;
    }

    public static int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public static void setYear(int year) {
        Person.year = year;
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(Person[] list) {
        boolean undone;

        do {
            undone = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.length - 1; j++) {

                    if (list[j].getYear() > list[j + 1].getYear()) {
                        list[j] = list[j + 1];
                        list[j + 1] = list[j];

                        undone = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (undone);
    }

    public static void printArray(Person[] myPerson) {
        int n = myPerson.length;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            System.out.println(myPerson[i].getName() + " ");
    }
}


public class MainPerson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person[] myPerson = new Person[] { new Person("Susanne Hansen", 1999), new Person("Hans Jespersen", 1896),
            new Person("Eva Gylden", 2789), new Person("Anders Aage", 1786), new Person("Ane Pulsar", 1345) };

        Person.bubbleSort(myPerson);
    
        Person.printArray(myPerson);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is your `Person` class. Your fields are `static` meaning all instances share the same value, probably `Ane Pulsar` as that is the last one being set. Remove all that static mess. Only your `bubbleSort`, `printArray` and `main` method should be `static`.

Comment: You need to assign `list[j]` to a temporary variable, say `tmp`,  before doing `list[j] = list[j+1]`, then instead of assigning `list[j+1] = list[j]` just do `list[j+1] = tmp`.

Comment: Also, in your `bubblesort` method why do you have two for loops if `i` is never used?

Comment: Thank you soooo much M. Deinum and Jonny Henly. Now it is working :D

Comment: You've now changed the code *in the question*, so the question no longer makes sense. That's not going to help anyone in the future. Please roll it back to the code that actually shows the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated Code which generates output as you require:

```java
class Person {
    private  String name;
    private  int year;

    public Person(String name, int year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public  String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public  void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public  int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public  void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    
}


public class Main {
    
    public static void bubbleSort(Person[] list) {
        boolean undone;

        do {
            undone = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.length - 1; j++) {

                    if (list[j].getYear() > list[j + 1].getYear()) {
                        Person temp = list[j];
                        list[j] = list[j + 1];
                        list[j + 1] = temp;

                        undone = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (undone);
    }

    public static void printArray(Person[] myPerson) {
        int n = myPerson.length;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            System.out.println(myPerson[i].getName() + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person[] myPerson = new Person[] { new Person("Susanne Hansen", 1999), new Person("Hans Jespersen", 1896),
            new Person("Eva Gylden", 2789), new Person("Anders Aage", 1786), new Person("Ane Pulsar", 1345) };


        bubbleSort(myPerson);
    
        printArray(myPerson);
    }
}
```

There are few mistakes in your code:

1. You need to store the value that you are replacing in a temporary variable in the bubble sort function.

Your Code is:

```java
 if (list[j].getYear() > list[j + 1].getYear()) {
                        list[j] = list[j + 1];
                        list[j + 1] = list[j];

                        undone = true;
                    }
```

Need to update it to:

```java
 if (list[j].getYear() > list[j + 1].getYear()) {
                        Person temp = list[j];
                        list[j] = list[j + 1];
                        list[j + 1] = temp;

                        undone = true;
                    }
```

What was happening in your code was as you didn't store the value in a temporary variable the object at list[j] was getting lost.

2. Never use `static` in POJO/Data classes.
   FYI POJO is a class that contains only data and functions to manipulate the data.

Using `static` will make java create the Object only once in memory and they will live throughout the lifecycle of the program.

3. Using the Class name in the POJO class.

As you have used `Person.name` or `Person.year` it will create problem, always use this `this.name`/`this.year` keyword to reference objects that are inside the same class.

4. Do not write functions that required to be called only once or twice inside Data/Pojo class. This will reduce the memory usage and running time.

You need to look into details of the [Static Keyword](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-java/),[this Keyword](https://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword) and [POJO Classes](https://www.javatpoint.com/pojo-in-java).

Comment: To understand what the code difference is run your code and my code through a diff checker: https://www.diffchecker.com/